# The expression contains undefined function call DATEADD() | FilterExpression | Datetime filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, sqldatasource, dateadd

I have a grid-view and I want to filter it to display data only in a certain date interval (from date A to date B, include A and B)

I use SqlDataSource and FilterExpression, initially I use this FilterExpression:

```
FilterExpression="Submitted_time >= '{0}' AND Submitted_time <= '{1}'">
```

But data in {1} date is not included in the result (although I use **'<='**) (probably because of time (hour/minute) so I managed to add 1 day to the {1}:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CTECS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Event] ORDER BY [Id] DESC"
                        FilterExpression="Submitted_time >= '{0}' AND Submitted_time <= DATEADD(day, 1, '{1}')">
                        <FilterParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="FromDate" ControlID="oCalendar1" PropertyName="SelectedDate" DefaultValue="1/1/1800" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="ToDate" ControlID="oCalendar2" PropertyName="SelectedDate" DefaultValue="1/1/3000" Type="DateTime" />
                        </FilterParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But then Visual Studio give me : ***The expression contains undefined function call DATEADD()***

Any solution here, my objective is only to include the data of the date {1} to the result...

Comment: don't know if it'll make a difference, but you're missing quotes on the start/end of {1} for your updated function w/ dateadd.  I'm assuming this is for sql server?  I haven't worked with sqldatasource so I wasn't sure and thought i'd ask :)

Comment: doesn't matter they both made same error. initially I put '{1}' then change to {1}, the {1} type is DateTime not string so ' ' doesn't matter here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Editors_IDEs/Q_22907598.html

[In reference to dateadd in filterexpression]

> Nope, it's a string style filter only. You'll have to evaluate the 
>   date and then pass it in as a string to the filterexpression

E.g. you can't use built in sql functions in your filterexpression (at least that's how I'm interpreting it).  You'll need to do a `DateTime.AddDays(1)` to your `oCalendar2` date or `ControlParameter toDate`

Comment: You're right maybe this function is not supported in filterexpression, I did using the code behind to add 1 day to the control oCalendar2 to make it work, just want to know if filterexpression can handle this and look like it doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your date needs to have quotes surrounding it. Right now its treating it like a double.

Try:

```
DATEADD(day, 1, '{1}')
```

Comment: same error, initially I put '{1}' then change to {1} only but they all not working though (the {1} type is DateTime not string so ' ' doesn't matter here)

Comment: Also, I believe it should be DATEADD(d,1,'{1}') if I remember correctly. See if that solves the issue.

Comment: Tried DATEADD(d,1,'{1}') and it is a no-go either, same error. I mean I have it working by add 1 day on my ooCalendar2 control in code behind but that is kind a detour, maybe I just need to stick with it for awhile

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, and yeah that is a work around but not ideal. Also, if you are using the next day, make sure to use **<** instead of <= because that will pull the next day if a record has a min time.